# Ordenar matriz de mayor a menor

Tags: c#, visual, matriz

hace un tiempo vine pidiendo ayuda para solucionar un problema con mi matriz, el señor Antonio S.F me solucionó el problema pero ahora tengo otro.

Pero ahora agregué a la matriz algo nuevo que es aparte del nombre y la edad es un resultado que se saca a una evaluacion.
Necesito que al imprimir la matriz se imprima en orden del mejor resultado al peor es decir de mayor a menor.

El me creó este programa que solucionaba el problema mio:

```
using System;

namespace PlaterotiNuevo
{

struct regPersona
{
    public string Nombre;
    public int Edad;
}

static void Main ()
{
    const int NUM_MAXENTREVISTAS = 3;

    // Creamos la matriz
    regPersona[] Persona = new regPersona[NUM_MAXENTREVISTAS];
    
    // Albergará el número de Personas que hacen la entrevista.
    int nPersonas = 0;
    // Para saber si queremos otra entrevista. Inicialmente sí, por eso
    // se inicializa con "S" 
    string otraEntrevista = "S";
    
    while (otraEntrevista.ToUpper() == "S")
    {
        Console.Write("Ingrese su nombre y apellido por favor: ");
        Persona[nPersonas].Nombre = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("Ingrese su edad: ");
        Persona[nPersonas].Edad = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        
        // ---- Código HACER ENTREVISTA
        
        
        // ----
        
        nPersonas++; // Incrementamos ya que una persona 
                     // hizo la entrevista.
        
        // Si ya alcanzamos el máximo número permitido de
        // entrevistas, salimos del bucle.
        if (nPersonas == NUM_MAXENTREVISTAS) break;
        
        // Para terminar debemos saber si hay otra persona
        // preparada para hacer la entrevista.
        Console.Write("\nIniciar otra entrevista (S/N): ");
        otraEntrevista = Console.ReadLine();
    } 

    // Imprimimos el arreglo y lo recorremos según las Personas
    // que hicieron la entrevista.
    Console.WriteLine("\n-- Personas Entrevistadas --" );
    for (int j = 0; j < nPersonas; j++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Persona[j].Nombre + " con " + 
                          Persona[j].Edad.ToString() + " años.");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Y donde esta el problema en el orden? ahi no hay nada que ordene...

Comment: exacto, necesito algo que me lo ordene

Comment: Si esto es un ejercicio, y quieres aprender, la idea es que lo intentes vos. Si no, solo vas a obtener una respuesta y no vas a saber hacerlo. Tene en cuenta eso.

Comment: Si, lo se, pero no es un problema que tuve hoy y quiero que me lo solucionen, tengo este problema desde hace dias y ya he intentado. No voy a aprovecharme de ustedes solo porque no quiero intentar las cosas. Igualmente gracias

Comment: si lo intentaste, nada mejor que mostrar que intentaste y entonces podemos guiarte por el camino correcto.. no importa si lo tenes hace dias o hace media hora... si lo intentaste, mostrando eso ya nos demostras que queres aprender y te podemos ayudar mejor y encaminar mejor a que aprendas...

Comment: nadie va a juzgar lo bueno o malo de tu intento... solo te vamos a decir en que te equivocaste, porque y como corregirlo.... ese es el placer de aprender a programar...

Answer (score 0):

Lo puedes hacer muy fácil al haber estructurado los datos en una estructura, la forma sería así:

```
struct regPersona
{
    public string Nombre;
    public int Edad;
    public float Resultado;
}
```

Añadimos un nuevo campo a la estructura para albergar el resultado. Y cuando ya disponemos de nuestro array completado con los datos hacemos lo siguiente:

```
    Persona = Persona.OrderByDescending(p => p.Resultado).ToArray();
```

Comment: Eso pondría dentro del for que hice para imprimir la matriz?

Comment: Justo antes, de esa forma ordenas y el bucle for sólo se encarga de presentar los datos.